# Selenium fails with "TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session" (in python), how to resolve it?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm using:

```
Firefox version: 63.0.3 (64-bit)

geckodriver 0.23.0
```

I'm trying to retrieve a specific webpage and I keep getting the message:
 **"TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session"**
in my geckodriver.log.
Firefox fails to load the webpage with selenium.

So for getting more info, I have added in my script:

```
opts.log.level = "trace"
```

This what I got:

> geckodriver::marionette   DEBUG   Connected to Marionette
>
> Marionette    TRACE   0 ->
>   [0,1,"WebDriver:NewSession",{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox"}]
>
> Marionette    WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this
>   session Marionette    DEBUG   [4294967297] Frame script loaded
>
> Marionette    DEBUG   [4294967297] Frame script registered
>
> Marionette    TRACE   0 <-
>   [1,1,null,{"sessionId":"4394672f-e908-4847-99af-2214ceabd4c0","capabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"63.0.
>   ...
>   9,"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.VAaCzXtuzQEd","moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin":false,"moz:webdriverClick":true}}]
>
> webdriver::server DEBUG   <- 200 OK
>   {"value":{"sessionId":"4394672f-e908-4847-99af-2214ceabd4c0","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"63.0.3","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:geckodriverVersion":"0.23.0","moz:headless":false,"moz:processID":2359,"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.VAaCzXtuzQEd","moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin":false,"moz:webdriverClick":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"linux","platformVersion":"4.15.0-39-generic","rotatable":false,"setWindowRect":true,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"unhandledPromptBehavior":"dismiss
>   and notify"}}} webdriver::server  DEBUG   -> POST
>   /session/4394672f-e908-4847-99af-2214ceabd4c0/url {"url":
>   "http://web.nli.org.il"} Marionette   TRACE   0 ->
>   [0,2,"WebDriver:Navigate",{"url":"http://web.nli.org.il"}]
>
> Marionette    DEBUG   [4294967297] Received DOM event beforeunload for
>   about:blank Marionette    DEBUG   [4294967297] Received DOM event pagehide
>   for about:blank Marionette    DEBUG   [4294967297] Received DOM event
>   DOMContentLoaded for http://web.nli.org.il/
>   Marionette    DEBUG   [4294967297] Received DOM event pageshow for
>   http://web.nli.org.il/ Marionette TRACE   0 <- [1,2,null,{"value":null}]
>
> webdriver::server DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
>
> webdriver::server DEBUG   -> DELETE
>   /session/4394672f-e908-4847-99af-2214ceabd4c0  Marionette TRACE   0 ->
>   [0,3,"Marionette:Quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
>
> Marionette    INFO    Stopped listening on port 40787 Marionette  TRACE   0 <-
>   [1,3,null,{"cause":"shutdown"}] webdriver::server DEBUG   Deleting
>   session

Searched for an answer but couldn't find how to overcome the issue, does somebody has a suggestion?

Comment: Please avoid using the `<blockquote>` markup for the errors as they gets word-wrapped and debugging the error becomes difficult.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
```

...is a `WARNING` message from the **Marionette** to the **server** i.e. the **webdriver** / **geckodriver**

As per the error stack trace, though you see this warning still your script/program is able to:

- Access the webpage `http://web.nli.org.il/`

  ```
  Marionette DEBUG [4294967297] Received DOM event DOMContentLoaded for http://web.nli.org.il/ 
  Marionette DEBUG [4294967297] Received DOM event pageshow for http://web.nli.org.il/
  ```
- At the end, the server is calling the `DELETE` endpoint for the session:

  ```
  webdriver::server DEBUG -> DELETE /session/4394672f-e908-4847-99af-2214ceabd4c0
  ```
- Which Marionette does successfully:

  ```
  Marionette TRACE 0 -> [0,3,"Marionette:Quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
  Marionette INFO Stopped listening on port 40787
  ```

---

### Conclusion

This `WARNING` message isn't a blocker issue for your *@Tests* and you can ignore it safely.

Comment: Your webpage is getting loaded properly, but you are invoking the method `driver.quit()` too early even before the elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) is visible. Hence as a user you don't see it. You need to wait for some time to see the entire [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) rendered.

Comment: I agree, thank you.
So how come the webpage doesn't get loaded? what it the reason?
all other sites i tried get loaded easily.

Comment: I have added time.sleep(50) seconds at the end before driver.quit(), right before the script terminates. but the same result :/